# Check string (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check text (ignore upper case ,lower case , use wildcard first text and end text , ignore space)

Example
compare text "Test SAmple round2" with "test sample"  ---> I want output = true
compare text "t.TestSAmpleround2 with "test sample"  ---> I want output = true

Please guide me for solve it by VBA,formular excel.

Thank you

Comment: `SEARCH` formula and `INSTR` function can do

Comment: I believe you'll need an extra reference in order to use regular expressions in Excel VBA.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost sure someone comes up with a clever regex solution for that, and it is likely possible to use an Excel formula, but the following function does the trick. It first removes all spaces from both strings, the string to be searched ("needle") and the string where you look for that string ("haystack"). After removing the spaces, it uses the `InStr`-function with option `vbTextCompare` - that makes the search case independent.

```
Function myInstr(ByVal haystack As String, ByVal needle As String) As Boolean
    haystack = Replace(haystack, " ", "")
    needle = Replace(needle, " ", "")
    
    myInstr = (InStr(1, haystack, needle, vbTextCompare) > 0)
End Function
```

You can use that function as UDF in your Excel sheet.

Comment: `myInstr(""Test Sample round2", "Tests Ample")` will return `True` (which a literal reading of the OP says it should).  Not a criticism of this answer, just pointing out the OPs criteria might be less than useful.  Just a warning for future readers

Comment: Right. There is absolute no way to get rid of such false positives.

Comment: You can split your search word and make an and logic state with the results

Comment: Nice. I could be wrong but as per OP, spaces needs to be ignored. In such a case there is no need to get rid of false positives. They are perfctly valid. On a separate note, you may also want to remove spaces which are actually unprintbale charactcers (OP may not be aware of this).

Comment: Excel formula to achieve this `=ISNUMBER(FIND(LOWER(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(B1)," ",""))),LOWER(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(A1)," ","")))))` Where `A1`  has "Test SAmple round2" and `B1` has `test sample`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Note that your formula would not remove the NBSP (char number `160` or `A0`)

Comment: just a slight modification of last function line with same result :-) `myInstr = UBound(Split(LCase(haystack), LCase(needle))) > 0`